# Pass argument to a Controller from Action Filter

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, action-filter

Can I pass an argument from Action Filter to a controller and specifically through the parameters (in ASP.NET Core) ?

For example:

```
public class CategoryController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ServiceFilter(typeof(ApiFilter))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string dataComingFromActionFilter)
    {
        //use dataComingFromActionFilter
    }
}
```

And

```
public class ApiFilter: IActionFilter 
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        //maybe something similar to
        context.sendToActionAsArgument['dataComingFromActionFilter'] = "data";

    }
}
```

Comment: Look promising: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.actionexecutingcontext.actionparameters?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_ActionExecutingContext_ActionParameters

Comment: Yes it is available for ASP.NET MVC. I am looking for an equivalent function in ASP CORE

Comment: Right, sorry. But you have the controller instance as the contexts property, could you use it? Or the RouteData?

Comment: Yes the controller is available in the context, How can I manipulate or set the values passed as arguments through this controller context

Comment: RouteData or any function that changes the arguments  &  is callable from the Action Filter Context.

Comment: The objective is to receive the values in the action method and through the parameters

Comment: Define an interface that exposes a dictionary. Impéement that interface on the controller. Cast the controller property to the interface and conditionalky set the dictionarry in the filter. You should be able to  see the values in the action method.

Comment: That's really smart! but I have one concern: Tasks are being called asynchronously. and if this controller gets 2 requests at same time. What would happen to this property ?

Comment: Each request has its own unique context.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can use

```
 context.ActionArguments["dataComingFromActionFilter"] = "data";
```

for updating existing action parameter. If you need to add new parameter, then

```
context.ActionArguments.Add("dataComingFromActionFilter", "data");
```

then you can reach it through  Controller Action

Comment: Thank you for helping. Setting the parameter worked perfectly. And I have a question about adding a new parameter. How can I use the added parameter in the controller?

Answer (score 6):

In the attribute set values into Items collection of HttpContext:

```
context.HttpContext.Items.Add("DataFromAttribute", date);
```

And In the controller read them in the same way:

```
this.HttpContext.Items["DataFromAttribute"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with code the below to see It work.

```
public class PersonFilterAttribute: Attribute, IAsyncActionFilter
    {
        public PersonFilterAttribute()
        {
        }

        public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
          context.ActionArguments.Add("personService", new PersonService("Thomas", 29,"Miami");       
          await next();
        }
    }
    
And In the controller read them in the same way:

this.HttpContext.Items["personService"];
```